# Wireless Display on Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: display

I have an Smart TV in "Wireless Display" mode. How do I use that remote screen as an remote display (dual) to my laptop screen?

Example: extended wireless display on windows

Comment: You mean to cast your laptop's screen to the TV?

Comment: I mean to use my TV as my secondary screen to my laptop's screen. @LuisAlvarado

Answer (score 4):

WiDi/Miracast for Linux projects seem to be abandoned (https://01.org/wds , for example). The only workaround is to set up a DLNA server on your Linux box. It is well explained at https://www.lg.com/ca_en/support/product-help/CT20098023-1348676620463-file-sharing-dlna .

EDIT: You will need to install minidlna and make sure it is running. The laptop and TV must be connected to the same LAN/WiFi network. New source, media-sharing, should appear in the list of available sources on the TV.

Comment: Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.

Comment: I don't see how this answers the question at all, the link just point to how to serve content, not extending the desktop as the OP asked

Comment: Extended wireless display is stated as an example. Streaming video/pictures is just another example. While the former is impossible, the latter works fine. Votting down the only existing solution for wireless display in Linux seems like hidings features of free open-source system.

Answer (score 2):

Smart TVs' wireless display modes are implementations of Miracast (or Wi-Fi Display) technology under different commercial names. Miracast standard comprises a sink (receiver, Smart TV in this case) and a source (trasmitter, ubuntu in this case).

In Ubuntu, you can install gnome-network-displays through means of Flatpak system, and better be on Ubuntu 21.04 cause it has several bugfixes and features relevant for Miracast. Note that gnome-network-displays is still considered "experimental" by its authors, but it's worth a try by now.

Comment: 21.04 is not out yet.

Comment: Right, 21.04 beta is out right now, I haven't pointed that out